# Access Filename or FULL Path of selected image from gallery?

Tags: ios, xamarin

How can i access Filename or FULL Path of selected image from UIImagePickerController gallery?

but i am getting referenceURL as null from the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl.

here is my code.

```
  NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
    if (referenceURL != null) 
        Console.WriteLine("FIle path : " + referenceURL.Path.ToString ());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
            if (referenceURL != null) 
                Console.WriteLine("FIle path : " + referenceURL.Path.ToString ());
```

Comment: Thank you walter! my current code is same like this but its not working each time i am getting this null, any thoughts ? :(

Comment: Can you please tell, how you got the full path of selected image from gallery. @ManzooPK

Comment: Did you get any solutions to this issue? I'm having the same challenge.

Comment: I found a solution to this and posted my answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748598/xamarin-ios-referenceurl-from-uiimagepickercontroller-always-null/34753408#34753408](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748598/xamarin-ios-referenceurl-from-uiimagepickercontroller-always-null/34753408#34753408)

Answer (score 0):

At this time (2019), the `referenceURL` type property is deprecated (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/infokey/1619171-referenceurl)). You can access an image path this way using Xamarin iOS :

```
private void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
{
   string myImagePath = (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.ImageUrl] as NSUrl).Path;
}
```

**NB** The path ressembles something like this :

/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/648C613E-F8FB-40D0-884B-303E825CBC49/tmp/8FAF7BEC-81C2-4B13-9D99-D840B3EF2C1D.jpeg